# C# - Controller can't see service

Tags: c#

**Controller** cannot see **Service**. When I push add request on my API, it gives me **code 500 error**. [This is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVBeL.png)  
Can anyone help me ?

Controller:

```
 

     [ApiController]
     [Route("[controller]")]
     public class ToDosController:Controller
     {
        IToDoService service;

        public ToDosController(IToDoService _service)
        {
            service = _service;
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public void Add(ToDo toDo)
        {
            service.Add(toDo);
        }
```

Service:

```
    public class ToDoService : IToDoService
      {
        IToDoFW database;

        public ToDoService(IToDoFW _database)
        {
            this.database = _database;
        }
        public void Add(ToDo toDo)
        {
            database.Add(toDo);
        }
      }
```

This is my *program.cs* codes :

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 
    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at 
    https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    builder.Services.AddDbContext<ToDoContext>();
    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
      app.UseSwagger();
      app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }
    IServiceCollection services;
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
```

`Fw` means that `FrameWork` . . . . I hope you can help me about it , thanks for reading guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the service to your `IServiceCollection` in your `Program.cs` (for .NET6 and higher) or `Startup.cs` (.NET 5.0 and lower).

```
services.AddScoped<IToDoService, ToDoService>();
```

Comment: Thanks for help, how can I add it ? it gives me error. I will update my question, please check bottom of question

Comment: add right after `builder.Services.AddDbContext<ToDoContext>();` 
`builder.Services.AddScoped<IToDoService, ToDoService>();`

if it worked, dont forget to mark the answer as helpful

Comment: thanks for help ! I need 15 reputation for it but I upvoted your answer !  thank you :)